# Изучение GLSL

Tags: книги, glsl

Что конкретно нужно знать для должного уровня понимания и осознанного написания шейдеров (как простых так и сложных)? Или большинство шейдеров пишутся по уже известным алгоритмам? Если это так, то - где о них можно почитать.

Начинаю я с [этой](http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Shading-Language-Randi-Rost/dp/0321637631) книги, но хотелось-бы иметь более одного источника, в идеале, книгу типа 'thinking in glsl' :)

Приветствуются любые советы и рекомендации по изучению сабжа